# ng-repeat with array of arrays

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have dynamic inputData array (length can be between 0 and 10 or 15) that looks something like this:

```
$scope.inputData = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
]
```

I need to generate td in the table with ng-repeat so I could have an only first item from each "sub-array" in the first iteration. Then only second item from each "sub-array", etc..  So table should be

```
th   th   th  th  th  th
1    1    1   1   1   1
2    2    2   2   2   2
3    3    3   3   3   3
...
```

And ng repeat should switch indexes in each iteration.

```
// first iteration: 
<td ng-repeat="item in inputData track by $index">{{item[0]}}</td>
// second iteration: 
<td ng-repeat="item in inputData track by $index">{{item[1]}}</td>
...
```

Can I somehow solve this only using ng-repeat or should I sort my arrays in the controller?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.inputData = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<table ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat='array in inputData' ng-init='parentIndex=$index'>
      <td ng-repeat='item in array'>{{array[parentIndex]}}
        <td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Now got an entire array in a row. 

'1, 2, 3, 4, 5'

Comment: @MatijaŽupančić, are you sure, check out code snippet?

Comment: @MatijaŽupančić, post your data, on which it is not work.

Comment: For the given solution, row number should match column number then only the entire array will be displayed. In above case, row no.= 6 and column no.= 7. So, we cannot get the entire array as the result.

Comment: I've got some array before so I have solved in this way.

`<tr ng-repeat="row in input.inputBuckets track by $index">
        <td>{{row.key | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="item in input.inputData" >{{item[$parent.$index]}}</td>
      </tr>`

These two arrays have the same length. And now works fine. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @MatijaŽupančić, and what is difference between your html and mine?

Comment: @ManvendraPriyadarshi, we can't show _"entire array"_, because main array length less then length of each descendant array, i.e. it has not square form.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov, thats what I was saying that this solution will work properly for square form but it will not display "entire array" if it's not in square form.

Comment: @ManvendraPriyadarshi, and this restriction coming from question requirement, it is not my person feature.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
    
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Example</title>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
        <script>
          var app = angular.module('app', []);
          app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
            var items = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
            ];
            
           $scope.items_transpose = transpose(items);
    
            function transpose(a) {
    
      // Calculate the width and height of the Array
      var w = a.length || 0;
      var h = a[0] instanceof Array ? a[0].length : 0;
    
      // In case it is a zero matrix, no transpose routine needed.
      if(h === 0 || w === 0) { return []; }
    
      /**
       * @var {Number} i Counter
       * @var {Number} j Counter
       * @var {Array} t Transposed data is stored in this array.
       */
      var i, j, t = [];
    
      // Loop through every item in the outer array (height)
      for(i=0; i<h; i++) {
    
        // Insert a new row (array)
        t[i] = [];
    
        // Loop through every item per item in outer array (width)
        for(j=0; j<w; j++) {
    
          // Save transposed data.
          t[i][j] = a[j][i];
        }
      }
    
      return t;
    }
            
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items_transpose track by $index">
                <td ng-repeat="i in item track by $index">{{i}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
      </body>
    </html>
```